# how to pass integer to array, where the array is contain some stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I hava an array called `screenData`, that is contain screen for my bottomNavigationBar.

for this case, i need to pass an int to all class on `screenData`.

is there any solution, so i dont need to manually input int to these class?

```
final screenData = [
    const homeTest(indexTheme: 2),
    const productPage(indexTheme: 2),
    const trading(indexTheme: 2),
    const inventoryPage(indexTheme: 2),
    const masterPage(indexTheme: 2),
    const financePage(indexTheme: 2),
  ];
```

the code is work fine but in the future i want the `indexTheme` can change, without i do it manually

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Theme` from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html.